# Using a template to cycle through a sequence of containers

Tags: c++, template, c++03

I'm trying to implement a template that takes a container as parameter. The template has a `getnext` method that cycles through the elements in the parameter. Take note that I'm not using C++11.

Header:

```
#pragma once

template<template<class, class> class TContainer, class TObject>
class cycle
{
public:

    explicit cycle( TContainer<TObject, std::allocator<TObject>> & container )
        : mContainer( container ), index(0) {}

    TObject getNext(int numObjectsToCycle) 
    { return mContainer[index++ % numObjectsToCycle]; }
private:
    TContainer<TObject, std::allocator<TObject>> & mContainer;
    int index;
};
```

Implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "cycle.h"

using namespace std;


class Processor
{
   int mIndex;
   vector<int> numbers;

public:
   cycle<vector, int> cycler;
   // Is it safe to pass numbers since it is declared first??
   Processor() : mIndex(0), cycler(numbers) {} 
   void update() { cout << numbers[mIndex++ % numbers.size()] << std::endl;}
   void addNumber(int x) { numbers.push_back(x); }
};


int main()
{
   Processor S;

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
   {
      S.addNumber(i+1);
   }
   cout << "using update" << endl;
   for (int c = 0; c < 10; ++c)
   {
      S.update();
   }

   cout << "using cycle" << endl;
   for (int c = 0; c < 10; ++c)
   {
      cout << S.cycler.getNext(5) << endl;
   }


   std::cin.get();

}
```

Any improvement or potential issues to the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would write it:

```
template<typename C>
class cycle
{
    C& mContainer;
    size_t index;
    using ref = decltype(mContainer[0]);

public:
    explicit cycle(C& container) :
        mContainer(container), index(0) {}

    ref getNext()
    {
        return mContainer[index++ % mContainer.size()];
    }
};
```

Notes:

- The template parameter is the container, `C`. This not only simplifies code, but also works for containers that do not follow a specific pattern, e.g. have more parameters than just a value type and an allocator type.
- The return type of `getNext` is automatically inferred from `C`. This is not just `C`'s `value_type` but a (non-`const`) reference to it.
- If I understand correctly from the title, `C` is supposed to be a *sequence of containers*? If so, the `value_type` is a container itself so it is even more important that a reference is returned from `getNext`.
- Why pass a parameter to `getNext`? To cycle correctly, you should use `mContainer.size()`, exactly as you do in `Processor::update`, right?
- `index` is of type `size_t`

With only a few changes, here is `Processor`:

```
class Processor
{
   size_t mIndex;
   std::vector<int> numbers;

public:
   cycle<std::vector<int>> cycler;
   Processor() : mIndex(0), numbers(), cycler(numbers) {}
   void update() { std::cout << numbers[mIndex++ % numbers.size()] << std::endl;}
   void addNumber(int x) { numbers.push_back(x); }
};
```

Notes:

- again, `mIndex` is a `size_t`
- `cycler` is a `cycle<std::vector<int>>`
- `numbers` is default-initialized
- `cycler` is safely constructed after `numbers`

Also, whenever you want to

```
using namespace std;
```

for convenience, only do it inside another (your own) namespace, never globally.

**EDIT**

I just noticed you're not using C++11. In this case, just use

```
    typedef typename C::value_type& ref;
```

instead.

Comment: The parameter to getNext allows me to limit the cycling to the first 5 out of 10 elements for example. So if I want only the 10 elements all the time, then I won't need a parameter.

Comment: @kunkka_71 Ok, then maybe you could have two versions if you also need the automatic one. In this case, one overload could call the other.

Comment: after using typedef as you've mentioned, using ref = decltype(mContainer[0]); does not compile. decltype is C++11 only?

Comment: @kunkka_71 Yes, the last `typedef ...` line is a *replacement* for `using ref = ...`.

Answer (score 2):

A few remarks:

- Try to avoid [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).
- In `Processor`, you should also explicitly call the constructor of the vector.
- Your cycle class could be templated on the container type only, and use `TContainer::value_type` instead.

Answer (score 2):

A few things about `update()`:

- It's less readable and maintainable to cram the functionality into one line.  Just declare it within the class and define it outside.  If the compiler decides that it should be inlined, it will do that for you.
- Prefer `"\n"` over `std::endl` when just outputting a newline.  The latter also flushes the buffer, which is slower and unneeded here.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n) for more information.
- `update` is not a very accurate name.  What exactly does it update?

Comment: It's actually a stripped down code so the contents of update is not just that. And the couts are really just to output them on the screen.